Troubleshooting Error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'data') - How to Handle Undefined Data in Stack Implementation?
Getting an Error "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'data')", while mapping the to get response form from API.
Try to solve checking and avoiding null by using '?'
eg:-
<div className="products-container">
            {!innerPage && <div className="heading">
                {title}
            </div>}
            <div className="products">
                {products?.data?.map((item) => (
                    <Product key={item.id} id={item.id} data={item.attributes} />
                ))}

            </div>
        </div>

Issue resolve for this specific 'Products' component but when passing the 'data' prop for other 'Product' component the the same "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'data')" occurred again
Process of fetching:-
api.js:-
import axios from 'axios';

const params = {
    headers: {
        Authorization: "bearer " + process.env.REACT_APP_STRIPE_APP_KEY,
    },
};

export const fetchData = async (url) => {
    try {
        const { data } = await axios.get(process.env.REACT_APP_URL + url, params);
        return data;
    }
    catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        return error;
    }
}

context.js:-
import { createContext, useState } from "react";



export const Context = createContext();

const AppContext = ({ children }) => {

    const [categories, setCategories] = useState();
    const [products, setProducts] = useState();

    return (
        <>
            <Context.Provider value={{
                categories,
                setCategories,
                products,
                setProducts,
            }}>
                {children}
            </Context.Provider>
        </>
    )
}

home.js:-
import { fetchData } from "../../utils/api";
import { Context } from "../../utils/Context";
const Home = () => {

    const { categories, setCategories, products, setProducts, } = useContext(Context);

    useEffect(() => {
        getProducts();
        getCategories();
    }, [])

    const getCategories = () => {
        fetchData("/api/categories?populate=*").then((res) => {
            console.log(res)
            setCategories(res)
        }
        );
    }
    const getProducts = () => {
        fetchData("/api/products?populate=*").then((res) => {
            console.log(res)
            setProducts(res)
        }
        );
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <Banner />
            <div className="main">
                <div className="layout">
                    <Category categories={categories} />
                    <Products products={products} title="Popular Products" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    );
};

Products.js:-
const Products = ({ innerPage, title, products }) => {
    return (
        <div className="products-container">
            {!innerPage && <div className="heading">
                {title}
            </div>}
            <div className="products">
                {products?.data?.map((item) => (
                    <Product key={item.id} id={item.id} data={item.attributes} />
                ))}

            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

Product.js:-
const Product = (id, data) => {
    
    return (
        <div className="product-card">
            <div className="thumbnail">
                <img src={process.env.REACT_APP_URL + data.img.data[0].attributes.url} alt="product" />
            </div>
            <div className="details">
                <span className="name">{data.title}</span>
                <span className="price">&#8377;{data.price}</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

You are not receiving the props correctly in Product.js component. They should be destructured and can not be accessed like function parameters.
Option-1:
const Product = ({id, data}) => {
    
    return (
        <div className="product-card">
            ....
        </div>
    );
};

Option-2:
const Product = (props) => {
    const {id, data} = props;
    // or use props.id and props.data
    return (
        <div className="product-card">
            ....
        </div>
    );
};


Thank you for your attention and your response on the Question Ravi, I will surely try this approach....
